# Find all list elements that are in a string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string and a list:

```
my_string = "one two three"
my_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

I would like to find ALL the substrings of `my_string` that are in `my_list`.

Here is what I tried:

```
matches = []

if any((match := sub_string) in my_string for sub_string in my_list):
   matches.append(match)
```

The result if I print matches is:

```
["one"]
```

I intend for the result to be:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Clearly, my code abandons searching for additional matches once it has found one match.
Questions:

1. How can I edit it to do what I require?
2. Is there a faster way of doing what I require?

Comment: the problem here is that `any` stops processing the inner iterator as soons as it gets the first truthy result. Just a list comprehension with an `if` guard, or the `filter` function will work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with list comprehension,

```
In [1]: [item for item in my_list if item in my_string]
Out[1]: ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Edit:

If `my_string = "onez two three"`, You can do this,

```
In [2]: [item for item in my_list if item in my_string.split()]
Out[2]: ['two', 'three']
```

This approach will work for both cases.

Comment: This will fail for example if `my_string = "onez two three"`, right?

Comment: @Mortz In that case you can do the second approach.

Comment: Yup. Your second approach works in the original case as well :)